# Remove the C# TextBlock inlines elements padding

Tags: c#, wpf, padding, textblock

About `TextBlock` UIElement in C#, we could add several `Run` object into it, which will be appended to `inlines` property. That's one way we show several pieces of text with different format(font, size and etc) in one `TextBlock`.

My question is: when I add, such as, two `Run` object into one `TextBlock`, there exist a padding between each `Run` object. For example, I add "12" and "34" `Run` objects, and finally they will be shown as "12 34" in the view. But what I need is they should be connected together as one word - "1234" - without that padding

Is there any setting we can use to prevent this padding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="12"/>
    <Run Text="34"/>
</TextBlock>
```

write the runs in one line like this

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="12"/><Run Text="34"/>
</TextBlock>
```

And the space will be gone.