# Spacing between inline elements in WPF textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I am adding Run elements to TextBlock control programmatically. I want these inline elements to be equally spaced.

```
TextBlock txtblck = new TextBlock();
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "a"});
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "b"});
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "c"});
```

now it gets displayed as "abc". But I wanted to display as "a b c". Is it possible? Please help me.

Also when we add the inline elements in XAML,the spaces are added between characters.But I get the text for the text block at run time only. So I cannot add the inline elements in XAML.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason there are spaces added between characters when adding runs in XAML is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500146/remove-the-c-sharp-textblock-inlines-elements-padding?rq=1).

To add spaces in code you can either add extra `Run` elements with spaces:

```
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "a"});
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = " "});
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "b"});
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = " "});
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "c"});
```

or append spaces directly to the text:

```
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "a" + " "});
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "b" + " "});
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "c" });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the spaces if you want them:

```
TextBlock txtblck = new TextBlock();
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "a " });
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "b " });
txtblck.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "c" });
```

There is no need to create any additional `Run` elements. And spaces are not added automatically between `Run` elements.